# Passing context implicitly across functions and javascript files in nodes.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have created a web server i node.js using express and passport. It authenticates using an oauth 2.0 strategy (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-canvas). When authenticated, I want to make a call such as:

```
app.get("/api/courses/:courseId", function(req, res) {
  // pass req.user.accessToken implicitly like 
  // through an IIFE
  createExcelToResponseStream(req.params.courseId, res).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Ops!");
  });
});
```

My issue is that i would like, in all subsequent calls from createExcelToResponseStream, to have access to my accessToken. I need to do a ton of api calls later in my business layer. I will call a method that looks like this:

```
const rq = require("request");    
const request = url => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    rq.get(
      url,
      {
        auth: {
          bearer: CANVASTOKEN // should be req.user.accessToken 
        }
      },
      (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
        resolve(response);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

- If i try to create a global access to the access token, i will risk
  race conditions (i think) - i.e. that people get responses in the context of another persons access token.
- If i pass the context as a variable i have to refactor a
  lof of my code base and a lot of business layer functions have to
  know about something they don't need to know about

Is there any way in javascript where i can pass the context, accross functions, modules and files, through the entire callstack (by scope, apply, bind, this...). A bit the same way you could do in a multithreaded environment where you have one user context per thread.

Comment: add a second parameter to createExcelToResponseStream ? ( sorry theres no other way, JS has lexical scoping)

Comment: I found a framework that aims to do what i wanted: continuation-local-storage  [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage). But i ran into some design issues because I could only retrieve that value from the storage 1 time. I needed to access the value multiple times unless I did some other refactoring... I ended up with using the second parameter approach. Not so pretty but I'm 100% sure that i don´t have race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you could do would be

```
.bind(req);
```

But that has has to be chained into every inner function call

```
somefunc.call(this);
```

Or you use inline arrow functions only

```
 (function (){
   inner=()=>alert(this);
   inner();
 }).bind("Hi!")();
```

Alternatively, you could apply all functions onto an Object, and then create a new Instance:

```
var reqAuthFunctions={
  example:()=>alert(this.accessToken),
  accessToken:null
};

instance=Object.assign(Object.create(reqAuthFunctions),{accessToken:1234});
instance.example();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Promise to avoid Race conditions.
Let's have this module:

```
// ContextStorage.js
let gotContext;
let failedGettingContext;
const getContext = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  gotContext = resolve;
  failedGettingContext = reject;
}
export {getContext,gotContext, failedGettingContext};
```

And this inititalization:

```
// init.js
import {gotContext} from './ContextStorage';
fetch(context).then(contextIGot => gotContext(contextIGot));
```

And this thing that needs the context:

```
// contextNeeded.js
import {getContext} from './ContextStorage';
getContext.then(context => {
  // Do stuff with context
}
```

This is obviously not very usable code, since it all executes on load, but I hope it gives you a framework of how to think about this issue with portals... I mean Promises...

The thing that happens when you call the imported 'gotContext', you actually resolve the promise returned by 'getContext'. Hence no matter the order of operations, you either resolve the promise after the context has been requested setting the dependent operation into motion, or your singleton has already a resolved promise, and the dependent operation will continue synchronously.

On another note, you could easily fetch the context in the 'body' of the promise in the 'ContextStorage' singleton. However that's not very modular, now is it. A better approach would be to inject the initializing function into the singleton in order to invert control, but that would obfuscate the code a bit I feel hindering the purpose of the demonstration.